# Expressions in Data Integrator tool on Informatica Cloud

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I use Data Integrator tool on IICS and I have  a csv file as source and need to change the data type on every single column as they all become nvarchar when read from the file. I have made an Expression transformation and use the To_Decimal function in each expression. But i find it very time consuming and booring to creat about a 100 expressions? This was easier and quicker to do in PowerCenter ... is there a smarter and quicker way to do this in IICS?

Br,
Ø

Answer (score 1):

This is where re-usability plays vital role.
create a reusable exp transformation which will take input and convert it to `decimal ()`. create 10 generic input and 10 generic output. One pair is shown below. Just copy and paste them 10 times and make sure the columns are properly set in formula.

```
in_col1 (string (150)) 
...
out_col1 (decimal(22,7) = To_Decimal( ltrim(rtrim( in_col1,7)))
```

Then copy it 10 times for your mapping. Pls note i used trim to remove spaces.
You can do this for date columns, trim space from string too.

Comment: Thank you :) I Used the Macro Expression ... that is basically what you describe.